# Netbeans not able to import FileUtils pacakge?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, apache-commons, fileutils

I am compiling my java software as **Netbeans IDE 8.2**. It uses the package FileUtils.

```
 import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

I am using below function from FileUtils:

```
 FileUtils.copyURLToFile(inputUrl, dest);
```

It builds fine and runs fine using Netbeans IDE.

However, when I run the jar file separately using the command:

```
    java -jar myProgram.jar
```

I get below error in the same line:

```
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
```

I don't understand why **FileUtils** is not getting packaged in jar file.
Please help.

This is my [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) Build file:

```
 <target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">
<property name="store.jar.name" value="iNetsControlProgramAllOs"/>
<property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
<property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
<echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
<delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
<mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>
<jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
    <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
    <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
<zip destfile="${store.jar}">
    <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
    excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
</zip>
<delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
```

Comment: It seems that you're not including the external library to the JAR you're exporting. I don't use NetBeans, but this guide might help you: https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/generating-executable-jar-file-with-all-dependencies-and-libraries-in-single-jar-using-netbeans-and-eclipse/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jar does not include the thirs party libraries, you must include them.

How do you build your myProgram.jar?

If you perform this with Netbeans itself, you may follow "Adding Necessary Libraries", on [this documentation](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html).

Otherwise, if not already the case, you may consider using [Maven](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html).

***Edit:*** OK, you are using [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/)
So, you need to include third party libraries in the "build path", which is the aim of your existing lines:

```
<zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
<zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
```

Can you check where is your third party Jar file providing FileUtils?

I guess it is NOT under dist, either dist/lib.

In addition, you should change the syntax to something like:

```
<zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
```

To ensure regarding ALL libraries in every sub-directories of dist/lib one.

Let me know if you need further explanations.

Comment: Hi Bsquare, How to include third party libraries . Can you please clarify?

Comment: Yes, what do you use to build your .jar file? => I updated my answer

Comment: actually i am using build.xml file which has a target called "package for store". When i click that , it creates the jar file.

Comment: Ok, so I guess it is an Ant file, can you copy/paste it in your original question please?

Comment: Thanks. You already have a **
    <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>** so either your third party libraries it NOT in this directory, either it is in a sub-directory. I completed my answer again.

Comment: Thanks Bsquare. It did fix the issue. Thanks a lot.